# crystal report and windows 7

Tags: windows-7, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i seem to have a problem with my reports, the problem is that ive tried to open a crystal report through project windows folders, by clicking twice on the icon OS gives the "Open With" choices i`ve choosed the visual studios 2008 so every file with the extension .rpt will open as visual studio file the icon turned from crystal report to a visual studio icon, and there was some problems in the connection with the data base through the report. how can return things back to normal....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the problem that windows didn't associate .rpt with Crystal Reports even though i had it installed.  Using CR 2013 and Windows 7, i had to "Open With..." to this path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86 
and chose crw32.exe

Answer (score 0):

You right click on any .rpt file and select "Open With..."

Then you look for Crystal Reports as your default program to launch. There should be a always checkbox to make the change persistent. If you do not see Crystal Reports on the list, you may need to select Browse and go to c:\program files\business objects or c:\program files\crystal reports

Comment: I did this, but I have CR2008 and CR2013 both, and even though I used browse and went to the 2013 version, it still opens in 2008.

Comment: If you have CR2013 open you can open from File, Open. Maybe persistence is changing when your various versions of CR is being opened.